# How to use the completionhandler for mapView in mapbox?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I want to run a function at the end of animation of the function setUserTrackingMode:
https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.9.0/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)setUserTrackingMode:animated:completionHandler:

The console outputs "animation ended", but not at the end. it is displayed immediately. I think I use the completionHandler wrong. How do I use the completion handler correctly?

```
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true, completionHandler: {() -> Void in
            
    print("animation completed")
              
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This function only works within

```
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
```

Before I tried it within `viwDidLoad`